# Database API join fields

Tags: entities, database

i've got a database query with a join like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.nid', 0, '<>')
  ->fields('n')
  ->range(0, 50);

$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_prospekt_owner','prospekt','prospekt.revision_id = n.nid');
```

Let's say I want to get the fields from my 'field_data_field_prospekt_owner' table in the result. How do I go about that?

i tried extending the fields function like `query->fields('n,prospekt')` but this throws an error.

`query->fields('n')->fields('prospekt')` isn't working, unfortunately. I'm getting a error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'prospekt': SELECT n.*, prospekt.* FROM {node} n {} LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_prospekt_owner} prospekt_2 ON prospekt.revision_id = n.nid WHERE (n.nid <> :db_condition_placeholder_0) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0 ) in main() (Zeile 42 von /var/www/asvg/prospekt_iframe.php)

Comment: `query->fields('n')->fields('prospekt');` is working fine, the problem is that `prospect` table alias does not exists. Provide full code.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$query->fields('n')->fields('prospekt');
```

See the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Afields/7) for more info.

Note that querying field tables this way is not recommended as the tables are created dynamically. You should only fetch field data via APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If i provide the fields to select for the joined table, it works... But it doesn't if i want to select all the fields by omitting the second parameter to `SelectQuery::fields()`.  The work around is to call the latter after the join so that the whole query would look like:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition('n.nid', 0, '<>')
  ->fields('n')
  ->range(0, 50);
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_prospekt_owner','prospekt','prospekt.revision_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('prospekt');
```

If i provide the fields for `prospekt` in the query builder, it works also:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition('n.nid', 0, '<>')
  ->fields('n')
  ->fields('prospekt', array('col1', 'col2'))
  ->range(0, 50);
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_prospekt_owner','prospekt','prospekt.revision_id = n.nid');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for another problem when I dropped on your question.

You can add your field using addField such as:

```
$query->addField('prospekt','prospekt_owner_value','owner');
```

You can use the field alias 'owner" to access the returned value.